# JQuery Get current ID of Widget

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have have the following

```
<div id="dualList"></div>
```

And I have written a plugin but for the sake of testing I have stripped it away.  I am having problems with the plugin displaying the id of the div.

```
<script>
(function($) {
    $.fn.DualList = function() {
    var thisControl = $(this);
    alert(thisControl.attr('id'));
}
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

And its bound on document on ready using
    **$("#dualList").DualList();**

Any ideas why the ID isnt echoing out?

Comment: What browser?  It works for me in FF.  http://jsfiddle.net/YeTvp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, as far as I can tell, [it does work](http://jsfiddle.net/ya97q/).

However, there are a couple of things that are not optimal in your code.  You can't be sure that there's just one onject selected (it could be a class selector, for all you know).  You should therefore iterate through all the members of the selection. Second, you don't need the jQuery constructor to get the `id` property. You can do it just with `this.id`:

```
$.fn.DualList = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        alert (this.id);
    });
};
```

[Working example of this style of code](http://jsfiddle.net/ya97q/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Widget is a collection wherever invoked, so

```
$(this.element[0]).attr("id")
```

will get you the id of the first element and so on..